# Complete ANOVA table for two predictor variables

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I am asked to complete the ANOVA table for my data which has two predictor variables since it is multiple linear regression. So far, I have found SSRes using the formula $\sum(Y_i^2)$ - $\hat{\beta}'X'Y$ which was equal to 676.69 and I have found the MSR which was 16.11. I'm not sure how to find the Sum of squares for x1&x2 to complete this table. Can anybody help?

The data given is: Y = X$\beta$ + $\epsilon$
and $\sum{Y_i^2}$ = 6424.30
as well as the following matrices: 
X'X = (45.00, 207.10, 3589, 207.10, 1021.54, 165.50, 35.89, 165.50, 32.53)  (I'm not sure how to insert a matrix into this forum so the numbers are read left-right in order of a 3x3 matrix.

X'Y= (450.36, 2353.04, 341.53). 
$(X'X)^-1$ = (0.49, -0.07, -0.20, -0.07, 0.01, 0.00, -0.20, 0.00, 0.26) and

The least squares estimate of $\hat{\beta}$ of $\beta$ is: $\hat{\beta}$ = (-5.070, 4.120, -4.871).

I am assuming I need to find SSReg for the entire model and then find it for x1 and subtract them both to find it for x2 but I am stuck on how to find SSReg for the model.

Comment: Which ANOVA table?

Comment: it looks like this: source of variation     sum of squares   df   mean squares and on the side it says x1, x2 residual and the totals underneath it. I'm stuck on calculating SSReg.

Comment: I updated my question with data provided